# Cannot insert value into database using XAMPP and Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm a student and new to the concept of JDBC. I have a problem. I created a test Java program with GUI.

It will ask the user to enter their name in the textfield, and when the user clicks the "Add Record" button, the text typed into the textfield should be uploaded to the database. I already created a sample table and it only contains one field.

When I run the said program, the exception statement prints out a Null error. However, I don't understand this since my
[insert data method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seao8.png)  contains a System.out.print and it prints out the value typed in the textfield just fine.

This is my code for the sample GUI I made:

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;

public class UIData extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static JTextField textField;
    public static String Name;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIData frame = new UIData();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public UIData() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 823, 472);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JLabel lblInsertName = new JLabel("Insert Name: ");

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnAddRecord = new JButton("Add Record");
        GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
        gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(65)
                    .addComponent(lblInsertName)
                    .addGap(107)
                    .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(149)
                    .addComponent(btnAddRecord))
        );
        gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(12)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(3)
                            .addComponent(lblInsertName))
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(133)
                    .addComponent(btnAddRecord))
        );
        contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
        btnAddRecord.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                UIDBConnect connect = new UIDBConnect();
                connect.insertData();
            }
        });
    }



}
```

And this is my code for connecting to the said Database

```
   import java.sql.*;

public class UIDBConnect extends UIData {
 private Connection con;
 private Statement st;
 private ResultSet rs;
 private PreparedStatement pst;
 public static String str = textField.getText();

 public void DBConnect() {
     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
         st=con.createStatement();

     } catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());

     }
 }


 public void insertData() {
     try {

         System.out.println("Inserting records into the table...");
         System.out.println(str);
         st = con.createStatement();
         String sql = "INSERT INTO tbltest " +
                       "VALUES ('" + str + "')";
          st.executeUpdate(sql);

     } catch(Exception ex) {
         System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());

     } 
 }

}
```

The error prints out [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOxLT.png).

I hope I explained that clearly.

Edit 1: When you use ex.printStackTrace(); The error prints out like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at UIDBConnect.insertData(UIDBConnect.java:43)
    at UIData$2.mouseClicked(UIData.java:84)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Does the table tbltest exist in your database?

Comment: @RalfRenz Yes it does.

Comment: Please use `ex.printStackTrace()` instead of `System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());` and post the full stacktrace **as text** (not as a screenshot).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I've already added it in my post.

Comment: The fields `con` and `st` are `null`, because you never called the method `DBConnect()` (if you intended it as a constructor it should have signature `public UIDBConnect()`. In general you really should not decouple using a connection from using a connection. There are other things wrong with your code (eg: you really should be using a prepared statement instead of concatenating values into a query string: that is highly unsafe).

Comment: In UIDBConnect you set once str=textField.getText(). You should set it, when textField has a value your interested in.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel do you mind explaining it more?

Comment: You initialize the connection and statement in the method `DBConnect()`. You never call that method.